# What is the scripting language for WinNT environment?

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

I understand that a Batch Script is what you call a script made in the WinNT environment, but a batch script is also a general term for a type of script that performs a batch operation in any language.

Is there a set, Scripting Language name that you would use on a resume to explain that you can script in the WinNT environment? Because even Linux has BASH Scripting etc.

EDIT: Let me add this, pertaining to someone who can create .BAT/.COM scripts, what kind of scripting would that formally be called?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "WinNT environment". Only Windows NT <= 4.0, or do you mean any Windows version which was based on that, including WinXP, Vista, Win7?

Comment: Windows does not have a single scripting language. You can write scripts in VBScript, JavaScript, PowerShell, or boring Windows batch language. (I think you're asking for the name of the boring batch language. I don't think it has a name, really, but if you write "Windows batch language" people will probably understand.)

Comment: I would suggest "Windows command shell scripts" or something similar.  (And I think you mean .cmd not .com!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you leave those newer scripting languages like VBScript, Powershell or Javascript aside, there is just "Win32 Shell Scripting" or "Windows command shell" - I don't think that this "language" has a better name. Not even the Wikipedia article on `cmd.exe`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_Prompt

mentions a language name.

Comment: @scottm: was thinking almost the same when I saw yours :-)

Comment: maybe we should create the name for it right now. Let's create history for 11/11/11... we now dub thee... TheSuck language =D

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version, you've got [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript).

If you're using a newer version of Windows Server, you probably either have or could install [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) (which comes with its own scripting environment).

Comment: VBScript and powershell are different however. Yes they can be done in the windows environment, but when you create a script in a .BAT or .COM file, what do you call that scripting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript, also. Just run any .js file with cscript.exe

Comment: talking about windows .BAT/.COM scripts and if there is a true formal name for it for someone that creates them.

Comment: Then you would just call it batch scripting. Because all you are doing is batching commands. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file